# Reload asset link helpers w/o full page reload

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, turbolinks

I've developed a Rails app that uses a randomly selected "card" based on uploaded files in the given directory. This card name is used to load the appropriate content within the template as well as load the appropriate JS and CSS manifest files.

What I'm looking to do is create a button that can find a new randomly selected card and refresh the corresponding code, in the `.mid` div and in the `head` tag, but I'm having issued with the latter.

I'm using this following line to successfully refresh the card but the same approach doesn't seem to work when targeted at the head, event when putting the link helpers in a partial to get re-rendered.

```
    $('.mid').load('/public/shuffle');
```

Here's the method I'm calling in the controller to shuffle the content.

```
def shuffle
    @card = Dir['app/views/cards/*/'].shuffle.first
    if params[:card]
      @title = params[:card]
    else 
      @title = Dir[@card+'*.html.erb'].first.gsub("app/views/cards/", "").gsub("/_index.html.erb", "")
    end
    render partial: '/cards/'+@title+'/index'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i get your question right but normally a controller will render a layout which includes a yield in which it can place its content. So the main layout does not change all the time but the dynamic content provided by the controller (usually in the body) will adapt to the input provided. That could be the reason why your mid-div is changing but your head is not since it is somewhat staticly rendered from your layout file.